# Importing data from csv file into PostGRESQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I am a newbie to using postgreSQL and am trying to import data from a csv file into a postgreSQL database set up on my local desktop. (Create an empty table under a database, right clicked on the empty table, selected 'import' and then provided the csv file, format, header, and delimiter.)

However, I get a message that reads: 'Failed (exit code 1)'.
Can anyone guide on what could the reason be? Attached an image of the same error.

[image]

The csv file looks like this:[image]

Comment: To get an answer you will need to provide, in your question, table definition and sample of the CSV file. Also the error message from the Postgres log.

Comment: @Adrian Klaver: Sure!, I've included snapshots of the same Adrian Klaver!

Comment: That is not the Postgres log, that is the pgAdmin error message. There maybe more information in `More details...`, but what you really need to look at is the Postgres log itself.